# angular-datatables dynamically change empty table message

Tags: angularjs, datatables, extend, angular-datatables

I know one can easily change the default config for empty message during the table init.

```
 DTDefaultOptions.setLanguage({sEmptyTable:' custom'})
```

I have a page where I reload the table content from a http call and promise when based on user changing filtering parameters. I  was wondering if it's possible to change the empty message so that the text reflects error in http call and no results in the database.
It looks like the code is static.How could I extend the native angular-datatables code to allow changing the empty message after table initialisation.

Answer (score 4):

Table cell with empty message has class `dataTables_empty`. If you want to display a message other than "No data available in table", you can use the code below:

```
$('#example .dataTables_empty').text('Error: Unable to load data');
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkcmLsmz/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the reply but it doesn't work for angular. I ended up doing something like this

```
       if($.fn.DataTable.settings.length > 0){
            $.fn.DataTable.settings[0].oLanguage['sEmptyTable'] = errorMessage ;
       }else{
                 $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                    oLanguage: {'sEmptyTable': errorMessage}
                });
           }
```